# Compute Engine / gcloud in VM - is this the right way?

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I fiddled around with kubernetes and GKE and found it way to complicated for a simple Docker installation (in this case: a customized Wordpress container and mariadb as DB-container) so I created a VM on Compute engine (debian jessie) installed docker 1.11.2 and docker-compose. To get access to gcr.io I also installed glcoud. I added a firewall rule to get access to port 8080.

Everything works fine - The whole thing was up and running in ~15mins

My question now is: Is it appropriate / secure to install gcloud on the host vm???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to install gcloud on the host VM. I actually thought that it was preinstalled on most GCE images, so it's interesting to hear that it wasn't.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!